# How to search and get the second word in a string that has two of the search word in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a Python script that finds the word "Hold" in a list string and confirms if it is holdable or not.

```
File = [
    "Hold_Small_Far_BG1_123456789.jpg",
    "Firm_Large_Near_BG1_123456789.jpg",
    "Move_Large_Far_BG1_123456789.jpg",
    "Firm_Large_Far_BG1_123456789.jpg",
    "Hold_Small_Hold_BG1_123456789.jpg",
    "Hold_Small_Near_BG1_123456789.jpg",
    "Small_Small_Far_BG1_123456789.jpg",
]

for item in File:
    if "Hold" in item: return print('Yes, object is holdable.')
    else: return print('No, object is not holdable.')
```

The code above sees the first 'Hold' word and returns true. The holdable objects are the ones that have 'Hold' as the third word.

The problem is the code sees the first 'Hold' word and returns true. I want the code to check if there's a word 'Hold' in the filename while ignoring the first 'Hold' word.

Please note that I cannot split the string using the '_' because it is generated by people. So, sometimes it can be a comma, dot, or space even.

Is there an expression for this? Sorry for the bad English.

Thank you. :)

Comment: not really enough info to go off here; what exactly does a 'holdable' object have in its file name? Is it the word "Hold" as the third word always? Is it as the 3rd last word? Either way, you'll want to use regex `import re`

Comment: The holdable object images always have either 'Hold' or 'Holdable' as the third word. In addition, if the third word is 'Hold', then the first word of the word will always be 'Hold' as well. This is why I don't know how to target the third word if it is 'Hold' or not.

Comment: can you show some examples of non-holdable objects that start with the word Hold as well? Best to list a few examples so that the pattern is clear. Once you know that, you can design a regular expression (regex) to target the specific part of the string that you're interested in.

Comment: I have updated the thread. Please let me know if any info is needed.

Comment: What is "the third word" of the string? What is the rule that tells you what the "words" of the string are? To solve the problem, maybe you should start by implementing *that* logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex pattern:

```
import re
holdables = ['yes' if re.findall(r'\w.*(Hold)', x) else 'no' for x in File]

for x in holdables:
    print(x)
```

The regex here only assumes that 'Hold' is not the first word in the string but does exist elsewhere, since you said you can't be sure whether underscores or other delimiters will be present. If you need more stringent conditions for the regex pattern, you can always update it.

Comment: I've been looking for this. I will study more about regex. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question correctly, we want to find if the filename contains "Hold" anywhere ignoring the first occurrence. Without definite separators, however, it is difficult. Here are two approaches that I think could work:

1. Using regex like:

```py
import re
for fname in File:
    if re.match("(^.+Hold.*$)", fname):
        #code if hold is found
```

**Assumptions**: This answer relies on the assumption that Hold can only occur only in the third position and first position if it does occur. We ignore the first in this case and search for the third "hold"

```py
>>> re.match("(^.+Hold.*$)", "Hold_Small_Hold_BG1_123456789.jpg")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 33), match='Hold_Small_Hold_BG1_123456789.jpg'>
>>> re.match("(^.+Hold.*$)", "Hold_Small_Far_BG1_123456789.jpg")
>>>
```

2. Use `split()`

We can split the string with "Hold". When "Hold" is present in the third position, we get a list with either 2 or 3 elements.

```py
for fname in File:
    if len(fname.split("Hold")) == 3:
        #code if hold is found
```

Again the **assumption** is that Hold can only occur only at the third position and first position if it does occur.

```py
>>> "Hold_Small_Hold_BG1_123456789.jpg".split("Hold")
['', '_Small_', '_BG1_123456789.jpg'] #list with 3 elements

>>> "Hold_Small_Far_BG1_123456789.jpg".split("Hold")
['', '_Small_Far_BG1_123456789.jpg'] #list with 2 elements
```

Answer (score -1):

```
i = 0
while (i< len(File)):
    s = File[i]; ct = 0
    ct = s.count('Hold')
    if ct >1:
            print ('Yes, object is holdable.')
    else:
            print ('No, object is not holdable.')
    i+=1
```

Edited, now it works only if 'Hold' appears more than once.

Comment: This doesn't address the fact that "Hold" can't be the first word, so this still fails in those cases.